# NSArray will not initialize in my MVC view

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, nsarray, drawrect

The first few programs I wrote in ObjC worked but were a cluttered mess so this time I wanted to do it right and employ MVC.  All of the pieces work and have been tested and things were going great until I tried to copy an NSMutableArray from the model through the VC to the view.  The exact same format and code was used and works fine in another aspect of the program but this particular view uses drawRect and breaks if I don't retain the array.  When I do it causes a leak.  To isolate the problem and create a workaround I ended up loading the array directly from the pList.  It looks like this:

```
@interface HWView : UIView <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
NSMutableArray *drawStates; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *drawStates;
```

in the .m

```
@implementation HWView

@synthesize drawStates;

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[self HWVReset];
}
-(void)HWVReset
{
NSLog(@"HWVReset:");
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)   objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectorystringByAppendingPathComponent: @"PLIST_drawState.plist"];
self.drawStates = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]retain];
NSLog(@"drawStates:%@",self.drawStates);
[self setNeedsDisplay];
}
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
//draw code
}
- (void)dealloc 
{
[self.drawStates release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

So this runs but it leaks. I remove the retain from: "self.drawStates = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath]retain];" and it crashes.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you want strong instead of retain?

Answer (score 0):

Of course : [NSArray array] is an autoreleased object. So you'll be calling a deallocated object. Read about Autorelease in Apple's docs.

Comment: Thanks for commenting - I have read over the docs with regard to autorelease as you suggested but im afraid its my interperatation of the info that needs help.  Clearly the answer is there and I still don't see it.  By calling retain I upped the count and held the object so the program didn't crash...  Where do I release it to stop the leak without crashing again?  Every time I put release in anywhere it crashes.